# How to use PHP templating features properly?

Tags: php, html, templates, view, reusability

Before i get to the point, let me introduce the context :)
I've been working on the view layer of a MVC framwork i'm trying to develop. I've created several reusable views such as an accordion, a drop down menu, a text editor, a color picker, etc. Using this, i can do, for example :

```
<?php
$template = newView('Template');
$template->panel()->add(newView('Accordion')
    ->add('Accordion entry 1')
    ->add('Accordion entry 2')
    ->add('Accordion entry 3'));
$template->content()->add(newView('Block')
    ->add('Bla bla bla')
    ->add('Bla bla bla')
    ->add('Bla bla bla'));
echo $template;
?>
```

And that sort of things.
The problem is that, to be able to do that, i have to mix PHP and html code. For example : here is how i generate the HTML of a drop down menu :

```
public function __toString() {
    $output =
        '<nav'.$this->_getHeader().'>'.
            $this->_label.
            '<ul>';
    for($i = 0, $l = count($this->_entries), $last = $l - 1; $i < $l; ++$i) {
        if($i === 0) {
           $this->_entries[$i]->addClass('First');
        }
        elseif($i === $last) {
           $this->_entries[$i]->addClass('Last');
        }
        $output .= '<li>'.$this->_entries[$i].'</li>';
    }
    $output .=
            '</ul>'.
        '</nav>';
    return $output;
}
```

A developper could easily design this by beautifying the code using Firebug or reading the PHP code, but a designer wouldn't like it.
To solve this i would like to use the PHP templating system. This, for example, would be much more readable by a designer.

```
<table>
    <?php foreach($users as $user); ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $user->firstName ?></td>
        <td><?= $user->lastName  ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

My problem is, how can i do, using the PHP templates, to create reusable views ? For example, imagine that i have a view representing a picture thumb with a picture and details about it. If i need to display a page containing 100 of them, how can i do ? Should i require the view 100 times ? Will it be executed / parsed / loaded from the damn slow disk 100 times ?
I don't see how i could build some kind of "lego-style" view layer using the templaetes. Do you have any idea or even examples ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I'd argue that what you're terming a view isn't a view - a partial view at most. IMHO a view would generate the entire html page with calls to partial views for logical elements like accordions

Comment: Let's call that HTML parts then :)

Comment: @Basic I would argue that a View might itself simply consist of several Views and leave it at that. I don't see why a View that does not happen to be an entire HTML page should not be a regular View. Why make that distinction? Also, the way I see it, by defining a View as a HTML page, you're saying that a CSV file, a PDF document or JSON data can't be a View. And although I'm not an MVC expert, I'd say that the ability to switch between different formats with the same data, is pretty much precisely what makes MVC worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent repeated reading of a file, you can load a file once and save its contents to a variable.

Repeating rows is of a view's responsibility and is undesired to be inside template itself.

As for templating itself, I would recommend to avoid using pure-PHP templates in favor of passive templates with variables/placeholders like this:

```html
<!-- table.tpl - Template for table. -->
<table>
{{rows}}
</table>

<!-- table-row.tpl - Template for table row. -->
<tr>
    <td>{{first_name}}</td>
    <td>{{last_name}}</td>
</tr>
```

You can then replace template variables with their needed values. For example, in simplest case (real world templating is of course more sophisticated):

```php
$tableTpl = file_get_contents('tpl_dir/table.tpl');
$rowTpl   = file_get_contents('tpl_dir/table-row.tpl');

$rows = array(
    array(
        'first_name' => 'Lorem',
        'last_name'  => 'Ipsum'
    ),
    array(
        'first_name' => 'Foo',
        'last_name'  => 'Bar'
    )
);

$rowsFrags = array();

// This loop can be moved to a method of a template engine class.
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $names = array_keys($row);

    foreach ($names as &$name) {
        $name = '{{' . $name . '}}';
    }

    $rowsFrags[] = str_replace($names, array_values($row), $rowTpl);
}

$rowsCode  = implode("\n", $rowsFrags);
$tableCode = str_replace('{{rows}}', $rowsCode, $tableTpl);

echo $tableCode;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So basically you suggest replacing tokens by their values inside of the HTML code. It does look nice but i'm worried about performance here. Isn't doing all those str_replace slow ? Also why choosing a hand made templating solution instead of the built-in one which, i assume, is faster ?

Comment: Templating engine like illustrated in the my answer provides more clean template code (more friendly for designer in particular), more separation of data from presentation (a fundamental design feature of a good web application), and more control on output code (preventing redundant line feeds in particular). Performance is quite enough for most of real-world web-applications (I personally use a similar approach [in the form of a templating engine class with methods like `loadTemplate()`, `processVar()`, `processVars()`, `processList()`, etc.] on all websites made by me).